# DirectoryEntry secure ecrypted

Tags: c#, ssl, active-directory, ldap

Hi I have an exe which I run and it runs under the context of my logged in domain account. The code just queries active directory for users under a specific OU. I run this code from a machine which is joined to the forest: **CompanyNameDomain.NET**.

Now the security team are asking me to ensure that all communication between this script and the domain controller is secure, encrypted etc. Please note that I'm not passing username /password data in the DirectoryEntry() constructor. I have looked on StackOverflow and most of the questions are about how to encrypt authentication by passing username/password in the DirectoryEntry constructor. But my question is how to ensure all communication between this script and domain controller is encrypted? The code works without any issues. I just don't know if I need to do something else? I use :636 in the LDAP moniker value.

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.DirectoryServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

    public class CompanyNameExtranetUser
    {
        public byte[] objectGUID { get; set; }
        public string sAMAccountName { get; set; }
        public string givenName { get; set; }
        public string sn { get; set; }
        public string displayName { get; set; }
        public string telephoneNumber { get; set; }
        public string extensionAttribute1 { get; set; }
        public string extensionAttribute5 { get; set; }
        public string extensionAttribute8 { get; set; }
        public int userAccountControl { get; set; }
        public bool isEnabled { get; set; }

        private string _mail;
        public string mail { get { return _mail; } set { _mail = value.ToLower(); } }

        public string inviteId { get; set; }
        public string AzureObjectId { get; set; }

    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const int UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE = 0x0002;
            string ldapPath = "LDAP://CompanyNameDomain.NET:636/OU=CompanyNameClientsSCIMProv,DC=CompanyNameDomain,DC=NET";

            DirectoryEntry _de = new DirectoryEntry(ldapPath);

            string ldapFilter = "(&(objectClass=user)(extensionAttribute8=2))";
            List<CompanyNameExtranetUser> _CompanyNameExtranetUsers;
            SearchResultCollection src;
            string[] _attributeList =   {
                                            "objectGUID",
                                            "sAMAccountName",
                                            "mail",
                                            "givenName",
                                            "sn",
                                            "displayName",
                                            "telephoneNumber",
                                            "userAccountControl",
                                            "extensionAttribute1",
                                            "extensionAttribute5",
                                            "extensionAttribute8"
                                        };



            try
            {
                using (DirectorySearcher _ds = new DirectorySearcher(_de))
                {
                    _ds.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
                    _ds.Filter = ldapFilter;
                    _ds.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange(_attributeList);
                    _ds.Asynchronous = true;

                    src = _ds.FindAll();

                    if (src.Count > 0)
                    {
                        _CompanyNameExtranetUsers = new List<CompanyNameExtranetUser>();

                        foreach (SearchResult sr in src)
                        {
                            CompanyNameExtranetUser user = new CompanyNameExtranetUser();

                            foreach (string _attributeName in _ds.PropertiesToLoad)
                            {

                                try
                                {
                                    switch (_attributeName)
                                    {

                                        case "sAMAccountName":
                                            user.sAMAccountName = sr.Properties[_attributeName][0].ToString();
                                            break;

                                        case "mail":
                                            user.mail = sr.Properties[_attributeName][0].ToString();
                                            break;

                                        case "extensionAttribute1":
                                            user.extensionAttribute1 = sr.Properties[_attributeName][0].ToString();
                                            break;

                                        case "extensionAttribute5":
                                            user.extensionAttribute5 = sr.Properties[_attributeName][0].ToString();
                                            break;

                                        case "extensionAttribute8":
                                            user.extensionAttribute8 = sr.Properties[_attributeName][0].ToString();
                                            break;

                                        case "telephoneNumber":
                                            user.telephoneNumber = sr.Properties[_attributeName][0].ToString();
                                            break;

                                        case "givenName":
                                            user.givenName = sr.Properties[_attributeName][0].ToString();
                                            break;

                                        case "sn":
                                            user.sn = sr.Properties[_attributeName][0].ToString();
                                            break;

                                        case "displayName":
                                            user.displayName = sr.Properties[_attributeName][0].ToString();
                                            break;

                                        case "objectGUID":
                                            user.objectGUID = (byte[])sr.Properties[_attributeName][0];
                                            break;

                                        case "userAccountControl":
                                            user.userAccountControl = (Int32)sr.Properties[_attributeName][0];
                                            user.isEnabled = Convert.ToBoolean(user.userAccountControl & UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE) ? false : true;
                                            break;

                                        default:
                                            break;

                                    }
                                }
                                catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException Ex)
                                {
                                    // do nothing.                                                                 
                                }
                            }

                            _CompanyNameExtranetUsers.Add(user);
                            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}", user.mail));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception Ex1)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct. All you need is to connect to port 636. That's it.

The very first thing it does when the connection is established is an SSL handshake (exactly the same thing that happens in HTTPS). Then all other communication is over the encrypted connection.

Even though you are not specifying credentials, your credentials are being sent.